# Mark one test class with many categories

Tags: java, junit

I have to mark one test with multiple test categories using JUnit 4.11 annotation @Category.
Is it possible? If yes, please, give a little example code.

Comment: You cannot have duplicate annotations in Java, period. So the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @Perception: but you can pass multiple values to an annotation. Check my answer.

Comment: @JBNizet - indeed you can. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass an array of categories, as [shown in the javadoc](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html).

```
@Category({SlowTests.class, FastTests.class})
public static class B {
    @Test
    public void c() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx , answer was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class B {
       @Test
       @Category( { SlowTests.class, FastTests.class })
       public void c() {
       }
}
```

This is taken from the [javadoc](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/junit/junit/4.8/junit-4.8-javadoc.jar!/org/junit/experimental/categories/Categories.html) for `Categories`.